# Adding a custom field to the site identity menu

Tags: custom-field, menus

It seems by default WordPress provides fields for site-title and tagline.

I understand how to add (for example) the option to chose a logo, adding `add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );` to the functions.php file. However, how do I add fields for 'company name' and 'company division' or for any text field that is not already part of the WordPress theme support?

Answer (score 14):

You'll have to add your own customizer controls to achieve that.

So for example, if you want to add Company Name, you can use this code:

```
function my_register_additional_customizer_settings( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'my_company_name',
        array(
            'default' => '',
            'type' => 'option', // you can also use 'theme_mod'
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options'
        ),
    );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'my_company_name',
        array(
            'label'      => __( 'Company name', 'textdomain' ),
            'description' => __( 'Description for your field', 'textdomain' ),
            'settings'   => 'my_company_name',
            'priority'   => 10,
            'section'    => 'title_tagline',
            'type'       => 'text',
        )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'my_register_additional_customizer_settings' );
```

PS. Here you can find more docs regarding this topic: [Theme Customization API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API)

Answer (score 7):

This is all part of the [Customizer API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API); you'll create a [section](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_section), add a [setting](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference%5CWP_Customize_Manager%5Cadd_setting) to the section, then add a [controller](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference%5CWP_Customize_Manager%5Cadd_control) to the setting. Once complete you'll show it on your theme using [`get_theme_mod()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mod)

For your example, you would add the 'company name' to the Customizer like so:

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'mytheme_company_section' , array(
        'title'      => __( 'Additional Company Info', 'mytheme' ),
        'priority'   => 30,
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'mytheme_company-name', array());
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'mytheme_company_control',
            array(
                'label'      => __( 'Company Name', 'mytheme' ),
                'section'    => 'mytheme_company_section',
                'settings'   => 'mytheme_company-name',
                'priority'   => 1
            )
        )
    );

    // ..repeat ->add_setting() and ->add_control() for mytheme_company-division
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

Then to show this dynamic value in the theme, you'd go into a file like `header.php` or wherever you want it, and use:

```
echo get_theme_mod( "mytheme_company-name" );
```

Comment: Hmm... Wouldn't option be a better choice for settings like company name?

Comment: I've assumed he's working on a theme, not a plugin. A very good point made though.

Comment: Well, even if it is a theme, then you don't need to save it as a theme - Company name won't change very often. And since Site name is stored as an option... That's my way of reasoning in this case... :) But it's a detail, I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on a custom text menu setting to put in a footer, for example, using a default value as well:

```
function theme_footer_copyright( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'footer_copyright_setting', array(
        'default' => 'With ❤ from Prague', //default value of setting
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'footer_copyright_section', array(
        'title' => __( 'Footer Copyright', 'textdomain' ), //title of customizer menu section
        'priority' => 20, //order of display
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize, 'footer_copyright_control', array(
        'label' => __(' Copyright Text', 'textdomain' ), //label of the setting itself
        'section' => 'footer_copyright_section',
        'settings' => 'footer_copyright_setting',
    )));
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'theme_footer_copyright' );
```

Then to show it in theme (and the default value) use:

```
<?php echo get_theme_mod('footer_copyright', 'With ❤ from Prague'); ?>
```